# Didactically, how many and which layers can I identify in this CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This model will receive the pixels of an image as input.

```
def model(data):
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)
        shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
        reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
        return tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you can translate your code to `convolution -> relu -> convolution -> relu -> reshape -> linear -> relu  -> linear`, which will make 2 convolutional layers and 2 linear layers

Comment: @silgon: Some (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#ReLU_layer) would argue that ReLU itself constitutes a layer.

Comment: yeah, depending on the point of view, add 3 `relu`. I'm just not used to see the activation functions as layers in the papers.

Comment: So, these are the linears layers?

--> tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
--> tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases